# runtime exception while calling rest service using reast-easy

Tags: java, spring, rest, resteasy

Application is Spring 3.1.0 with EJB binding and WAS 7 deployment.

Trying to call Rest Service endpoint using resteasy-jaxrs and jaxrs-api jars with below implementation. But unable to call the endpoint, getting RunTimeException as below:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl
>
> **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl**

dependencies used in pom are

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
<exclusions>
<exclusion>
<groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Code to call rest Endpoint:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpParams params = httpClient.getParams();
            String serviceTimeout = "180000";
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 
Integer.parseInt(serviceTimeout));
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 
Integer.parseInt(serviceTimeout));
            ClientExecutor clientExecutor = new 
ApacheHttpClient4Executor(httpClient);
           ClientRequest clientRequest = new ClientRequest("url", 
clientExecutor);
            clientRequest.body(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, xml);
            logger.debug("Sending request :");
            ClientResponse<String> clientResponse = 
clientRequest.post(String.class);
```

Can anyone suggest on above issue.

Answer (score 0):

`RuntimeDelegateImpl` is part of the resteasy-client package. You'll need to declare a depedency to [resteasy-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-client) in your `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```